JavaFX: fxmlloader is recursive, and I keep getting null pointer exceptions on the instance variables in the controller class
This is the class definition of PostView, which is also the controller class for its fxml file. I am trying to make a javaFX social media app for a university assignment (due in a couple hours lol) called rogerbook. This class extends from AnchorPane as it is meant to be a post element to be added to the user's feed page. Every time I create a new PostView(); it keeps recursively calling the same error message, a LoadException as follows:
at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2722)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:946)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$RootElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:1302)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:230)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:757)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2853)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2649)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2563)
    at javafx.fxml@21/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at com.rogerbook.ui/com.rogerbook.ui.PostView.<init>(PostView.java:31)


it then prints out another NullPointerException on all the instance variables in the PostView class.
This is the class (minus the imports):

package com.rogerbook.ui;

public class PostView extends AnchorPane {
    PicPost post;
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
    @FXML
    private Label Username = new Label();
    @FXML
    private Label Title = new Label();

    public PostView(PicPost post){
        this();
        this.post = post;
        initializePostView();
    }

    public PostView() {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Post.fxml"));
        fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
        try{
            fxmlLoader.load();
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initializePostView() {
        if (post != null) {
            imageView.setImage(post.getImage());
            Username.setText(post.getAuthor().getProfile().getUserName());
            Title.setText(post.getTitle());
        }
    }
}

The program starts on a signup page.
this is the main application method that runs the program start:

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}

when signing up, its controller class calls the following method:
public class HelloController {

    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;

    @FXML
    private TextField username;
    @FXML
    public TextField password;
    @FXML
    public TextField name;
    @FXML
    private TextField password2;
    @FXML
    private Label errmsg;

    @FXML
    public void switchToHome(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("scenefeedpage.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        root = fxmlLoader.load();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    @FXML
    public void onSignup(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(password.getText());
        if(password.getText().isEmpty() || username.getText().isEmpty() || name.getText().isEmpty() || password2.getText().isEmpty()){
            errmsg.setText("Please fill all the fields");
            return;
        }
        if(password.getText().equals(password2.getText())){
            if(Roger.signup(username.getText().toLowerCase().strip(), password.getText())) {
                switchToHome(event);
            }
            else {
                errmsg.setText("Incorrect Password, or user does not exist");
            }
        }
        else{
            errmsg.setText("Passwords do not match");
        }
    }
}

The signup button redirects the user to the feed page where the feed controller adds a few PostView components to the feed area of the page (a VBox):
public class FeedController implements Initializable {
    private Stage stage;
    private Scene scene;
    private Parent root;
    Post post;

    @FXML
    ImageView imageView;

    @FXML
    VBox view;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        System.out.println("Initializing Feed");
        ArrayList<Post> feed = Roger.getFeed();
        System.out.println("Feed done");

        feed.add(new PicPost("Hi", new Image("com/RogerBook/ui/R.png"), new User("maro", "aa")));

        //PostView postView1 = new PostView((PicPost)feed.get(0));
        post = feed.get(0);
        view.getChildren().add(new PostView((PicPost)post));
        //view.getChildren().add(new PostView());
    }

    public void ViewPost(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("Post.fxml"));
        stage = (Stage)((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
        root = fxmlLoader.load();
        scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}


I genuinely dont know what to do right now, and I've been looking for a fix for hours on end and tried everything. pls help :D

Create and post a [mre]. Without that, we have to guess at parts of this and can only make guesses as to what is going wrong.

Fixes
Looking at the Oracle tutorial on FXML custom controls that use the fx:root method, it is different from your code.

In the tutorial there is no fx:controller attribute defined in the FXML.

You should remove a fx:controller reference in your FXML if you have one.


In the tutorial there is a call to fxmlLoader.setController(this);, which you don't have.

You should add a call to your code to set the controller on the FXML to your existing object.



I didn't try your code to see if it works with those fixes (that would require your FXML, which I don't have).  However, I assume that your application would work as expected (absent other errors) if you made those fixes.
Explanation
If you provide a controller in the FXML instead of setting the controller on the FXMLLoader in code, the loader will create a new instance of the controller rather than using an existing instance.  This is likely why you have issues such as null fields (the FXMLLoader is injecting field values into the instance it creates, not the instance you created).
You are getting into a recursive loop because you are loading the FXML in the controller constructor without setting the controller instance on the loader beforehand.  The loader then creates a new instance of the controller, which then loads FXML again, which then creates a new controller, etc, etc.
On the other hand, if you set the controller in code within the controller's constructor, the FXMLLoader will use the instance that you have set in your code (the one under construction), populating all of the injected FXML fields into that instance when the load method is called on the loader.  This will ensure that the controller you constructed is correctly initialized and prevent an infinite recursion loop where new controller instances are created in the controller constructor.
